# Check condition on upcoming line using readlines() function in Python

Tags: python, readline

I have `input.txt` file and `output.txt` file which are passed in argument in Python script. I am reading input file content using `readline()` function. Before I update to current line and write it to output file, I want to check some condition on upcoming lines as described below. Could you please provide me some guidance? Thank you.

I want to update current line with `internal_account` value (random number with 16 digits) from 11th location if line starts with `01065008` and following condition are met.

1. 5th upcoming line starts with `06` and
2. line start with `06` has value as `USD` from 6th character

****input.txt****

```
01065008200520P629658405456454
02BRYAN ANGUS      56425555643
0300000000000000000HUTS7858863
04PROSPECTUS ENCLOSYUSS574U623
05AS OF 05/13/20   45452366753
06Q47USDTFT        87845566765
```

`input.txt` file has pattern:

```
1st line will start with 010065008
2nd line will start with 02
...
6th line will start with 06
1st line will start with 010065008
...
```

***What I have tried?***

```
import random
import sys

infile=open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
lines=infile.readlines()

outfile=open(sys.argv[2], 'w')
internal_account = random.randint(1000000000000000,9999999999999999)

formattedStr = ''

for line in lines:
    if line[0:8] == '01065008':
        formattedStr='%s%s%s'%(line[0:10],internal_account,line[26:])
        outfile.write(formattedStr)
    else:
         outfile.write(line)
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check forward in the text file, read all the lines into a list then use the line index to check forward lines. Use the `enumerate` function to the track the line index.

```
ss = '''
01065008200520P629658405456454
02BRYAN ANGUS      56425555643
0300000000000000000HUTS7858863
04PROSPECTUS ENCLOSYUSS574U623
05AS OF 05/13/20   45452366753
06Q47USDTFT        87845566765
'''.strip()
with open ('input.txt','w') as f: f.write(ss)  # write data file

###############################3

import random
import sys

infile=open('input.txt')   #open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
lines=infile.readlines()

outfile=open('output.txt','w')  #open(sys.argv[2], 'w')

internal_account = random.randint(1000000000000000,9999999999999999)
print('internal_account', internal_account, end='\n\n')

formattedStr = ''

for i,line in enumerate(lines):
    line
    if line[0:8] == '01065008' and i < len(lines)-5 and lines[i+5].startswith('06') and lines[i+5][5:8] == 'USD':
        formattedStr='%s%s%s'%(line[0:10],internal_account,line[26:])
        outfile.write(formattedStr)
        print(formattedStr.strip())
    else:
         outfile.write(line)
         print(line.strip())
outfile.close()
```

Output

```
internal_account 2371299802657810

010650082023712998026578106454
02BRYAN ANGUS      56425555643
0300000000000000000HUTS7858863
04PROSPECTUS ENCLOSYUSS574U623
05AS OF 05/13/20   45452366753
06Q47USDTFT        87845566765
```

Comment: If input file is too large, it will have issue with List, right?

Comment: The file would need to be quite large to have an issue. In that case, you would need to read 6 lines ahead of the line you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

You were not far from finding a good solution. Using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) on input lines let use use the index to check future lines so you can verify if all your conditions are fulfilled. You need to catch [IndexError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError) so that no exception is raised when there are not enough lines left.

Other minor modifications I made in your code:

- Use [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) statement to handle file opening to prevent having to close file yourself.
- Use [startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) wherever you can to make the code clearer.
- Use scientific notation when you can to make code clearer.

```py
import random
import sys

input_file, output_file = sys.argv[0:2]
internal_account = random.randint(1e15, 9999999999999999)

with open(input_file, "r") as stream:
    input_lines = stream.readlines()

with open(output_file, "w") as stream:
    for index, line in enumerate(input_lines):
        try:
            update_account = (
                line.startswith("01065008")
                and input_lines[index + 5].startswith("06")
                and input_lines[index + 5][5:8] == "USD"
            )
        except IndexError:
            update_account = False

        if update_account:
            line = line[0:10] + str(internal_account) + line[26:]

        stream.write(line)
```